# Viewing E&R on iPhone Safari - No stylesheet

Tags: support, feature-request, website

Quite often, when I view the site on my iPhone safari browser, I loose the stylesheet and I'm left with a black and white unformatted view of the website.

I've tried clearing the cache, restarting, etc, but no difference.

Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: @Kortuk: Not really a feature request though... More of a bug I would say.

Comment: Yeah, thought the same thing, but it could be classified as either. Bug:does not work on iphone safari. Feature request: would like it to! I know the feature-request is a tag that they will see, I was not sure bug was and do not have a ton of time to look it up. I figure at least they know about it you can get feedback as to status and they see someone is having an issue.

Comment: @Kortuk: Good point... leave it as feature request and see what happens. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: As a side note, the style for the mobile site on android has changed to something incomplete. (Its no longer the sketchpad style)

Comment: @W5VO: Yes, it seems to have been kinda fixed on the iPhone, so I'm guessing android and iPhone are now using the same stylesheet. It's not quite right though... it's seems to be a black and white version much like the meta site.

Answer (score 1):

See:

- ["View standard site" option for mobile devices?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81169/view-standard-site-option-for-mobile-devices)
- [Don't use mobile theme on iPad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81165/dont-use-mobile-theme-on-ipad)

Yes, it looks like butt on my Droid too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i do and its annoying. I have to view it on my iphone as half of the site is blocked at college :/. Its supposed to be a full HTML site and the browser is supposed to support HTML5 but it obvious doesn't.

Comment: Why in the world would E&R (or any Stackexchange site, for that matter) be blocked at a college?  Isn't asking and answering questions what they *want* you to be doing?

Comment: Don't ask IT guys are rubbish i could do there job better than them and for less money. And btw i have ;)

Comment: that is crazy!